# How can throw java exception in rhino

Tags: java, rhino

Using org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.11 library to execute my custom java script code.

```
Context context = Context.getCurrentContext();
context = context != null ? context : Context.enter();
context.compileString("throw MyException();"), "mySourceName", 0, null).exec(context, context.initSafeStandardObjects());
```

Already tried used exception name in quotes, but that is not the solution what  need.

`"throw 'MyException();'"`

The same result if trying use java.lang.Exception

```
Context context = Context.getCurrentContext();
context = context != null ? context : Context.enter();
context.compileString("throw Exception();"), "mySourceName", 0, null).exec(context, context.initSafeStandardObjects());
```

Is there any way to passing java exception in rhino as passed java script error.

```
Context context = Context.getCurrentContext();
context = context != null ? context : Context.enter();
context.compileString("throw new SyntaxError("I am throwing ...");"), "mySourceName", 0, null).exec(context, context.initSafeStandardObjects());
```